# How to use AMD APP Profiler

Tags: opencl, profiler

The title pretty much says it already. I've looked through the AMD website and the help files associated with the AMP APP Profiler without a tutorial.

Is there any documentation out there that somebody can reference me to which explains how to use the profiler instead of only describing which amazing features it has (like the help files do without end). It's really frustrating reading that OpenCL is all rainbows and sunshine and not being taken seriously like that on every search attempt.

I never even used more than one profiler before (XNA Game development) and I guess that I may just have looked at this thing from a whole different perspective, in this case I need to figure out just how to start, and try hooking it up to third party software which I start up from my project. Just a "default" start tutorial will do already.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Well I just managed to generate something from a test project without third party software with good old "try untill you die" and am looking at some data. Also just learned I can't use any other tools like gDEBugger so that's off the table.

EDIT2: I need to find out if I can manually attach the APP profiler to a process that uses OpenCL technology now instead of having to run this from a binary source directly, there's multiple components at work in the current design and using the binaries directly would force major changes which needs to be avoided. Is it possible to attach a process in such a manner as something digestable for the profiler?

EDIT:

This problem is no longer relevant for my work

However it would be a lie to say I would not gladly like to know if a process can be directly fed to the profiler. So if anyone is kind enough to provide an answer in the long run just focus on that and ignore the rest of the question for a "correct" answer if you would please.

Comment: +1 for "all rainbows and sunshine".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two main ways of using the AMD APP Profiler:

1. [From within the Microsoft Visual Studio](http://developer.amd.com/tools/AMDAPPProfiler/html/usingthepluginsection.html)

   [With the command line mode of the AMD APP profiler](http://developer.amd.com/tools/AMDAPPProfiler/html/usingthecommandlinesection.html)

You can also find a tutorial section about the AMD APP Profiler in Chapter 12 of the [Heterogeneous Computing with OpenCL](http://www.elsevierdirect.com/ISBN/9780123877666/Heterogeneous-Computing-with-OpenCL) book.

For your question: no, you can't attach the AMD APP Profiler to a running process.

Comment: Thank you, this fully answers all aspects of the question in a short and clear manner. Im flagging it as correct and upvoting.

Comment: AMD links are both dead. I propose using http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/archive/amd-app-profiler/getting-started/using-the-command-line-interface/ instead.